# How it is the way that the proxy we connect Discript changed when we check in Google "Whatymisoip"

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

I try to make a tool to change change IP address in the desired time but when I check the ip diwhatismyip does not change

```
try:
    while True:
          url = "http://www.google.com"
          check = open(inputss,'r').readlines()
          ip = random.choice(check)
          auah = {"https":ip}
          poop = ip.strip()
          Sabyan = requests.Session()
          Sabyan.proxies=auah
          conn = Sabyan.get(url)
          time.sleep(inputs)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to read [ask] and How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can change your IP address using the following simple script if you are using a windows machine:

```
import os
import time
os.system("ipconfig /release")
time.sleep(5)
os.system("ipconfig /renew")
```

this should do the job, you can then scrape your IP address